# How to bypass the SameSite and Secure object of setting Cookies when I don't have a secure URL?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, session-cookies, samesite

I have recently Pushed by Server and Webapp to the cloud. It is still in the testing phase and we're working with the default links given for both the server and Website. These links are normal HTTP and not Secure. I'm setting some cookies when the user logs in, but the client is not saving the cookies now. It's throwing an error stating Set-cookie was blocked because sameSite is empty so it has been set to Lax.

Questions :

1. I have tried setting the sameSite to None. But this also requires me to set secure as true. Which is not possible as the links are still HTTP only.
2. If I do not set the SameSite, It moves it by default to Lax. So it blocks my cross site cookie.
3. Is there anyway I can get this to work by someway completely avoiding SameSite or making it to none and still bypass the secure parameter?

Note : [ There server and Website have different URLs and these links are of EC2 (server) and S3 static host (website) ]

Comment: "Is there anyway I can get this to work by someway completely avoiding SameSite or making it to none and still bypass the secure parameter?" - In short, **no**, there is not. That's by-design. You can secure your website for free with ACME and LetsEncrypt, so there's no excuse for not running a secure web-service today.

Comment: Thanks @Dai I'll look into it once.